# How can we measure the subjectivity in the scientific papers?

Tags: writing, science

The subjective decisions come up many times in the process of paper writing/doing research. These decisions' consequences are added up at the end. I didn't find research that would actually measure somehow this subjectivity in papers.

I'm wondering to quantify the subjectivity individually while the process is on.
I thought first I would just count the number of such decisions... One approach would be to ask people, to note each time when they decide about something that could have been put in another way... Do you know a better approach? I would appreciate any idea!

Comment: Can you give examples? Also, what discipline are you considering?

Comment: The entire process of writing is innumerable decisions on how to put something another way.

Comment: How do you decide that a certain decision was taken not taken objectively?

Comment: What makes a decision "objective"?